# How to check the number of layers in a neural network in python and when should we increase the layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Please add a minimum comment on your thought, so that I can improve my query. Thanks. -)

---

I am working on the `MNIST` dataset and write some `CNN` code. However, I am confused about some of the points with the `CNN` code. How to know the number of layers in a neural network? With my current understanding, I think this has 6 layers with 4 hidden layers. Is that right? and what if I need to extend to 10 layers? how to do it?

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(28, kernel_size=(3,3), 
                    input_shape = ...))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
```

Comment: What do you mean by `number of layers in dataset`? Can you please clarify that?

Comment: number of layers like input layer + hidden layer +output layer

Comment: datasets do not have layers, that is why people are confused by your question.

Comment: Oh im sorry.. I meant number of layers in the convolutional network

Comment: Suppose if some one asks me how many layers are there in the above model, what is the answer?  is it 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you print `.summary()` of your model you would get

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 26, 26, 28)        280       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 13, 13, 28)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 4732)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               605824    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 607,394
Trainable params: 607,394
Non-trainable params: 0

print(len(model.layers)) # 6
```

As you can see you built a deep neural network of **6** layers - some of them are `trainable` layers and some of them are `non-trainable` layers.  So, if anyone asks you about the number of your model's layers, it would be simply **6**.

---

And, how to extend or add more layers into this. Well, that's very simple like filling water in the glass. Like this

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Dense, Conv2D, Dropout,
                                     Flatten, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3,3), 
                    input_shape = (28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.summary()
print(len(model.layers)) # 10
```

Now, take note of this, though using `tf. keras` (or another framework like `pytorch`) we can so easily do such things, but we should consider what we are doing and what for. I won't describe much on this because it's out of the scope of this question. But I would highly recommend you to check `tf. keras` official [code example](https://keras.io/examples/vision/).

---

The term **Hidden Layer** is just a naming convention that was used early days frequently (AFAIK), mainly in a **Fully Connected Layer** (before `CNN`). That's why for simplicity, I would say just forget about this term. We should refer to a layer as `trainable` and `non-trainable`, that makes more sense now.

In your model, 1st `CNN` (trainable layer), 2nd `MaxPool2D` (non-trainable), 3rd `Flatten` (non-trainable), 4th`Dense` (trainable), 5th `Dropout` (non-trainable), and lastly at 6th `Dense`  (trainable). You can also see the `Param #` column in `model. summary()`, those who are non-trainable layer, their parameter is zero - no trainable variable in that layer. Let's say, in your model, the first layer stated as,

```
model.add(Conv2D(28, kernel_size=(3,3), 
                    input_shape = ...))
```

whatever the expected `input_shape` would be, pass the `3 x 3` size filters (total `28`) on the input and do convolution and produce some feature maps. So, at the end of this layer, we would get a total of `28` feature maps. Next layer

```
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
```

which is simply pooling the maximum value from those `28` feature maps, nothing else. So no computational operation - that's why so non-trainable parameter.

---

**Hidden Layer** simply refers to that layer that is placed between the **Input** layer and **Output** layer in a deep neural network. But in your model, the first layer which is `Conv2D` is a hidden layer, it's not the input layer. Here, the input layer is implicitly present when we pass the `input_shape` argument to the first `Conv2D` layer. So, if we take the **Hidden Layer** naming convention concretely, we can say, in your model, there is **5** hidden layer (from first `Conv2D` to `Dropout`). And The input layer is implicitly present and the output layer is the last `Dense` layer.

Comment: Thankyou so much M.innat :)... so the first layer is the convolutional layer, 2nd: maxpoolin,3rd faltten, etc right? also arent maxpooling and flatten layers hidden layers?  thanks and regards :)

Comment: Updated the answer, please look.

Answer (score 5):

While counting the number of layers in a Neural Network we usually only count convolutional layers and fully connected layers. Pooling Layer is taken together with the Convolutional Layer and counted as one layer and Dropout is a regularization technique so it will also not be counted as a separate layer.

For reference, the VGG16 mode is defined as a 16 layer model. Those 16 layers are only the Convolutional Layers and Fully Connected Dense Layers. If you count all the pooling and activation layers it will change to a 41 layer model, which it is not. Reference: [VGG16](https://in.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/vgg16.html), [VGG16 Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf)

So as per your code you have 3 layers (1 Convolutional Layer with 28 Neurons, 1 Fully Connected Layer with 128 Neurons and 1 Fully Connected Layer with 10 neurons)

As for making it a 10 layer network you can add more convolutional layers or dense layers before the output layers, but it won't be necessary for the MNIST dataset.

Comment: Thanks mate.Its really helpful :)

Comment: you stated 1 Convolutional Layer with 28 Neurons... But with usage of flatten does it not become 728[28 * 28] neurons?

Comment: @AntonyJoy The convolution layer is of 28 Neurons only, which is then converted into a 1D array to pass as an Input to the next layer.

Comment: @AntonyJoy If you have heard about the VGG16 model, it is defined as a 16 layer model. Those 16 layers are only the Convolutional Layers and Fully Connected Dense Layers. If you count all the pooling and activation layers it will change to a 41 layer model, which it is not. I am attaching some links for your reference, [VGG16](https://in.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/vgg16.html), [VGG16 Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf). Hope you get some clarity about this.