# what is the number of layers in EfficientNetB2?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, efficientnet

Knowing that the total number of layers in EfficientNet-B0 is 237 and in EfficientNet-B7 the total comes out to 813, what is the total number of layers in EfficientNetB2 ?

Answer (score 2):

If you print `len(model.layers)` on EfficientNetB2 model with keras you will have 342 layers.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB2
model = EfficientNetB2(weights='imagenet')
print(len(model.layers))
```

You can do this with all other versions of EfficientNetBx if you wish.

But as [Pradyut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15088707/pradyut) said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66705121/16759649) normally not all layers are taken into account when we count them:

> While counting the number of layers in a Neural Network we usually
> only count convolutional layers and fully connected layers. Pooling
> Layer is taken together with the Convolutional Layer and counted as
> one layer and Dropout is a regularization technique so it will also
> not be counted as a separate layer.
>
> For reference, the VGG16 mode is defined as a 16 layer model. Those 16
> layers are only the Convolutional Layers and Fully Connected Dense
> Layers. If you count all the pooling and activation layers it will
> change to a 41 layer model, which it is not. Reference: VGG16, VGG16
> Paper
>
> So as per your code you have 3 layers (1 Convolutional Layer with 28
> Neurons, 1 Fully Connected Layer with 128 Neurons and 1 Fully
> Connected Layer with 10 neurons)
>
> As for making it a 10 layer network you can add more convolutional
> layers or dense layers before the output layers, but it won't be
> necessary for the MNIST dataset.

I hope I answered your question!